# webscoket, alias domain and https (ssl)

Tags: websocket, alias

I am creating a chat system using websocket, alias domain and https (ssl). I am using the site's IP address (wss://185.210.95.xxx:9072). There seems to be no problem with webscoket. Could the problem be in my alias domain definition? It returns error 1006.

```
$Server = new PHPWebSocket();
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');
$Server->wsStartServer("185.210.95.xxx", 9072);
```

Comment: java code : Server = new FancyWebSocket("wss://185.210.95.xxx:9072");